# Redux-saga testing channel with buffer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am currently testing redux-sagas and having issues with testing the actionChannel/buffer section of the code. This is the saga:

```
export function* getStatsFlow() {
  const parseChan = yield actionChannel(
    PARSE_STATS, yield 
    buffers.expanding(10)
  );

  yield fork(getAllDocumentStats);
  yield fork(getReadStats);
  yield fork(getWriteStats);

  while (true) {
    const { payload } = yield take(parseChan);
    yield call(handleParseAndPut, payload);
    yield put(finishStats());
  }
}
```

The test that I currently have for that saga is:

```
it('should begin looping', () => {
  const statsFlowSaga = getStatsFlow();
  const mockBuffer = buffers.expanding(10);
  const mockChannel = channel(mockBuffer);

  statsFlowSaga.next().value;

  expect(statsFlowSaga.next(mockBuffer).value)
    .toEqual(actionChannel(PARSE_STATS, mockBuffer));

  expect(statsFlowSaga.next().value)
    .toEqual(fork(getAllDocumentStats));

  expect(statsFlowSaga.next().value).toEqual(fork(getReadStats));

  expect(statsFlowSaga.next().value).toEqual(fork(getWriteStats));

  expect(statsFlowSaga.next(mockChannel).value)
    .toEqual(take(mockChannel));
});
```

The final expect is failing right now with an error of "patternOrChannel is not defined". I have tried just passing in a mockChannel without the mockBuffer passed into it (on definition) as well as how I have it above. All configurations that I have tried have yielded this same error. Is this because the channel and buffer are not "linked"? How would I go about resolving this or is there a way? Thanks!